# PHP mailer with BCc and Cc

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have problem with using PHP mailer class.The problem is when I send email after some time I get this error:
[image]

Also, when I put comment on Bcc and Cc part in php mailer code , nothing changes...still got the same spam mail in my inbox.
Here is my code for sending emails:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $change)) {

    $mail->isSMTP();  
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.xxx.xxx.xx';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('prigovori@xxx.xxx.xx', 'SOME ADDRESS');
    $mail->addAddress($someMail); /// Add a recipient

    $mail->addReplyTo('prigovori@xxx.xxx.xx');
    //CC and BCC
    //$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");  // i put those two lines under comments in order to disable email spam but nothing changes
    //$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'EMAIL SUBJECT';
    $mail->Body    =   '<h2 style="margin-bottom: 30px;color: black;">Some title</h2>
                        <div style="height: auto;display:block;margin-bottom: 20px;background-color: white;">
                            <p style="color: black;">Here is some email text</p>
                        </div>';




    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with your sending code - that's woking fine - it looks like there's a problem with the server that is receiving your messages. Why would you think that changing CC/BCC would make any difference to this response? The message is still sent in exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you can see, mail function sending mail to BCC/CC , even if i put blank bcc/cc address. Have you seen screenshot that i attached? There are two addresses left from php mailer demo ( bcc@example.com and cc@example.com )

Comment: You do know that those delivery notification messages may be sent to you multiple times after you have sent a message? The ones you're getting with those addresses in are probably from an earlier run of the program, not your most recent one. Messages to `example.com` should always be undeliverable anyway.

Comment: Yes, i know that, and i changed my code about 4 days ago, and there are some earlier messages that i sent (before i changed my code ) , and maybe mail server remember those messages. I dont know....

Comment: It's easy to check - set `SMTPDebug = 2` and watch the SMTP conversation - you will see the `RCPT TO` commands that include the 'phantom' BCC and CC addresses if it's really including them, though I doubt it is.